# How to recompile a JS file from a TS file when running node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have a system where you can reload files to update flags on them, this is how I would do it in Javascript:

```js
var a = require('./a.js');
a.foo // {foo:'foo', bar:'bar'};
// ...
delete require.cache[require.resolve('./a.js')];
// edit "a.js" when node . class is active
var a = require('./a.js');
a.foo // {bar:'bar'};
```

But in Typescript, where I run `tsc` then `node .` (I edit the .ts files instead of the .js files)

```js
import { a } from "./a";
a.foo // {foo:'foo', bar:'bar'};
// ...
delete require.cache[require.resolve('./a')];
// edit "a.ts" when node . is active
import { a } from "./a";
// invalid code ^ I can't just do *that*, so...
const a = require("./a.js"); // accommodate for the fact that everything will be in a .js file
a.foo // {foo:'foo', bar:'bar'};
```

In the Javascript example, the end result is just `foo`. In the Typescript example however, the end result is `foo` and `bar` existing on the object. This happens because I edited the TS file, not the JS file, and the JS file is what node actually cares about. Then, this leads me to think of some code like this:

```js
var a = require("./a.js");
import { exec } from 'child_process';
import * as util from 'util';
let pExec = util.promisify(exec);

console.log(a.foo); // {foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar'}

// ...
// edit ts file...

await pExec("tsc ./a.ts"); // wrap this in an async function
delete require.cache[require.resolve("./a.js")];
a = require("./a.js");

console.log(a.foo); // {foo: 'foo'}
```

That's pretty inelegant with having to promisify a synchronious function, then drawing shell commands into the mix (considering that this works), is there anything more elegant than this?

Comment: I would probably use a regular JS or JSON file for configurations. JS allows type annotations via `/** @type {...} */`, split out any actual logic into separate TS files.

Comment: Here's another thing @H.B., its a class's function that does the file 'reloading'